# ADFS - redirect to custom page after 401.2 - Unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net, wif, adfs

I have a ASP WebForms app using WiF 4.0 to make single sign-on with our ADFS server.

But it shows a IIS error page from ADFS server, when user is closed login box.

How can I specify a url of page where user should be redirected after failed login?

Comment: What do you mean by "when user is closed login box"?

Comment: Browser displays Window Security popup - to input username and password. And there are 2 buttons - "Login" and "cancel". So if he press "Cancel", this popup is closed, and user see IIS error page that access is not granted